# How to Run a Program from a Console Application?

Tags: c#, console, dos, batch-processing

I am looking for resources that have examples for creating a Console Application.  I am past the "Hello World" stage but am stumped at the point where I need to run an application.  I have the string that I need to run that I pulled from the batch file that I am trying to automate in a C# app.  I need help with knowing which classes and namespaces have the functionality I need to run it.

Edit: Sorry for the poorly asked question. I'll rewrite it.

I am trying to create a console application that will replace a batch file that I have partially written.  Some of the data and file manipulations that I need to do are more complex than can easily be done in a batch file.  So far I am reading, writing, and manipulating the files just fine.  I am having difficulty when trying figure out how to run a command to execute an application on the server with the proper arguments being passed in.

Update:  a coworker gave me the following code snippit which is exactly what I needed to move forward.  I am sorry the question was worded so badly.

```
    public static string MyDOSMethod()
    {
        ProcessStartInfo si = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
        si.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        si.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        si.UseShellExecute = false;

        Process p = Process.Start(si);

       p.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"cd \windows\system32");

        p.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");

        try
        {
            return p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return e.Message;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio? Creating a console application is really just a few button clicks. File->New Project-> Select Console Application. Otherwise you'll need to tell us what tools you're using or what else you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: This question needs clarification; I think he's asking how to run an executable from a C# application, but it can also be understood as a request about how to build a console application or how, in general, to find functionalities built-in in the .NET Framework.

Answer (score 3):

The question is not perfectly clear, what I understood is "I need to start an application from my console application; what class can I use?"

My answer is: you should have a look at the static method [`Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s.aspx) (and in general at the class [`Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) of namespace `System.Diagnostics`).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Execute_Command_in_CSharp.aspx), it will guide you through the usage of `Process.Start` and `ProcessStartInfo` (which runs a process and gives you feedback)

Comment: Yeah, I think that's what they are asking for.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend this introduction to C# if your new to programming.

http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial.aspx

In order to compile you need a compiler and a GUI to edit code in is also nice :o) Here you can use the free version of Visual Studio:

http://www.microsoft.com/express/

In Visual Studio just click new select console application and i think you will get a "default application" like Hello World that you can run and build.

Comment: Thanks.  But I'm not a new programmer, just have never had to write a console app.